# Querying the User table with a users objectId queried from another table

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to query my `User` table with the Users `objectId` queried from another table.

Here's my code:

```
func queryFriendsTable() {
    var queryFriends = PFQuery(className: "Activity")
    queryFriends.whereKey("type", equalTo: "friend")
    queryFriends.whereKey("fromUser", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    queryFriends.includeKey("toUser")

    var queryUserTable = PFUser.query()
    queryUserTable!.whereKey("objectId", matchesKey: "toUser", inQuery: queryFriends)
    queryUserTable!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.friendNamesArray.addObject(object["username"]!)

                    println(self.friendNamesArray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing is being returned when I run this query. I think the problem has to do with the fact that the `toUser` `objectId` in the `Activity` table is a pointer and not a string. (The `toUser` value I try to use in the `matchesKey` spot is a pointer)

So how can I get the `objectId` as a string from a pointer object using the `inQuery` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. Parse won't find pointers when looking through the User's class. Instead what you'll need to do is create a string variable and set it equal to the result of `queryFriends`. So what that means is you'll have to run that query first, get the pointer back, and access it's objectId field as a string in order to use it in your following query.